# Ruby .past? method on date is giving wrong result in IST timezone for AWS server in India with UTC timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, timezone

Im using the `.past?` method to check if the date is past date.
Im using AWS EC2 servers and then are in India region.

For the India time between 12 AM to 5.30 AM in the morning, If we convert IST timezone time to UTC and call the `.past?` method, it returns true.

```
time = "2023-02-07 02:24:59 +0530"

DateTime.parse(time).utc.to_date.past?

#It is returning true whereas it should return false
```

The server timezone is UTC

Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: It might be because you are using `to_date` after converting it to UTC, check by either avoiding it completely or by using `to_time`.

Comment: avoiding `to_date` or using `to_time` will always return false because it's a past time & not past date.

Comment: `DateTime.parse(time).utc.to_date #=> Mon, 06 Feb 2023` vs. `DateTime.parse(time).to_date #=> Tue, 07 Feb 2023`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the definition it's just defined as:

```
# Returns true if the date/time is in the past.
def past?
  self < self.class.current
end
```

`current` returns `Time.zone.now` when `Time.zone` or `config.time_zone` are set, otherwise just returns `Time.now`.

This leads to a real gotcha as you're comparing a time in UTC to the current time in another time zone and `<` doesn't take the TZ into consideration.

If you want to do a comparison and avoid this gotcha make sure both operands are in the same TZ:

```
date = DateTime.parse(time).utc.to_date
date < Time.now.utc
```